# Kendo treeview with support of drag and drop and right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to configure a Kendo UI Treeview, in order to support drag and drop and right click on the nodes. I wrote this Javascript/jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#treeview").on('mousedown', '.k-item', function (event) {
        if(event.which === 3) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').select(this);
            alert("right click... ");
        }
    });

</script>
```

The drag and drop functionality works... until I right click on an node. After, I cannot perform any drag and drop until I reload my page.

Any idea ?

Comment: do you have any eventlistener on contextmenu?

Comment: Hello, I tried with and without event listener. The result is the same : the drag and drop functionality is lost.

Comment: Do you get any errors? try using firebug

Comment: I don't get any error. I tried in Chrome and Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Show your code on how you initialize the kendo treeview.